# Not getting expected output in following sql server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What should be the output of the following two queries in sql server 2008?

```
select 2
except
select 0
union all
select 0
except
select 2


select 2
union all
select 0
```

The first query is giving output as 0 but I am expecting union of 2 and 0, while the second query is displaying expected result of 0 and 2 in result set.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 5):

In stages

```
select 2 except select 0
```

gives

```
2
```

Then

```
union all select 0
```

gives

```
2
0
```

Then

```
except select 2
```

removes the 2 giving

```
0
```

If you want 2 and 0, use

```
(select 2 except select 0) 
union all 
(select 0 except select 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just like math, the order is important and so are brackets.
Try this:

```
(SELECT 2 
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT 0) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT 0 
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT 2)
```